# I want to display the day of the date that I put in my array using moment

Tags: vuejs2

I'm displaying the list of holidays where in the array the specific day (e.g 'MMMM-01-YYYY' in my array it's written like this dateHoliday: "01") I want to catch the day included in my array and display it (e.g "Mon" like this.)

I tried using moment and what I achieved is to display the current day(today). I can't get the array the I want.

```
<template>
<h2>{{ Holiday.dateHoliday }}</h2>
</template>

import moment from "moment";
export default {
data() {
return {
  Holidays: [
    {
      id: 1,
      Month: "January",
      day: "Tue",
      dateHoliday: "01",
      Title: "new year's day",
      Description: "Description: Regular holiday."
    }

methods: {
    displayDay(){
    let dH = moment().format("ddd");
    this.dateHoliday = dH;
console.log(this.dateholiday);
    }
```

> edit

I tried Capt. Teemo's answer.
I changed one of my string in the array.

```
  day: "Tue",    
  dateHoliday: "01",
```

> to

```
  day: "01-01-2019",
  dateHoliday: "01",
```

> then in my template:

```
<h2>{{ Holiday.dateHoliday }}</h2>
<h2>{{ Holiday.day | convertDay }}</h2>
```

> But in the property(day) i don't want it to be specific (e.g 01-01-2019. I want it like 01-01-xxxx where its filtered? to the year i want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method in using `moment`:

I used vue `filters`. Add these lines after your `method`

```
methods: {
},
filters: {
    convertDay: function (value) {
        return moment(new Date(value)).format('ddd')
    },
}
```

then use the filter that you created:

```
<template>
    <h2>{{ Holiday.dateHoliday | convertDay }}</h2>
</template>
```

Comment: The day `ddd` displays only from 1-13. The rest is [25-31] `invalid date`

Comment: try to display the whole date. the there you can use my code: `{{wholedate | convertDay}}`. Note: date must be ISO 8601. you can check it here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/